# How To Convert An Invalid JSON String To Valid in C#

Tags: c#, json

```
{"Loan":"6F40CDFD026674","DOB":"2020-10-30","Payment":"Online","Address":"Can"t connect "}
```

This JSON string value created dynamically. How can we remove extra single/double quotes from the property value field.

I need this   "Address":"Can"t connect " to "Address":"Cant connect "

Final result will be need like below

{"Loan":"6F40CDFD026674","DOB":"2020-10-30","Payment":"Online","Address":"Cant connect "}

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier to fix the code that produced this string. A *human* can understand that `can"t` is suspicious, but what if the unescaped double quote appeared at the end of a string? Or if there was a single space between the unescaped double quote and the proper end of the value?

Comment: Guess you can check for valid sequences: `{"` or `":"` or `","` or `"}`

Comment: Who is creating the JSON? If it’s done by your side/organization use a proper serializer. If you can’t influence it: do you know if the Address field only has a fixed amount of invalid values? If yes, a simple string replace should suffice.

Comment: Fixing this mistake in json is problematic. This is not a problem you ***should*** be fixing. It's someone else's problem, or your own in another library

Comment: Without fixing the bad serializer, one can only use workarounds that can easily fail. Perhaps a regex that finds double quotes surrounded by digits/letters?  Eg use `\w"\w` with Regex.Replace.  But that would break if a bad double quote was surrounded by spaces. What if some field contained `"Bank says "Tough luck" "` ?

Comment: BTW if that JSON is produced by a payment service, they're *obliged* to fix it. They get paid a lot to get it right. You already pay them for use and support

Comment: Simple solution is to iterate the string and when you hit a " char, check if the char on index n+1 and n-1 is [a-z,1-9]..if so replace it toan empty char